# How to show private data of my webapp without using user authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, security, authorization, websecurity

I have made a webapp. This webapp has some private user data. When someone logs into the app, they can look at that data. However, I am creating a user application where, my app(app1) will be embedded in another app(app2) in an iframe. So, it can be assumed that whenever a user accesses app2 they are an authentic user. Now, when the user makes a request from app2, I want to show some private data in app1. I want this to happen without any authorization in app1 as the user is already authorized in app2. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the user authentifications datas in temporarys cookies (sessions cookies) at the connection. When a user open your applications, the app1 get the cookie content, and authenticated the user with the cookies. This cookies can contain the username or the password of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can make app1 and app2 share the same cookie. That is, set login cookie's  domain to .mydomain.com assuming app1's domain is app1.mydomain.com and app2's domain is app2.mydomain.com.